# How to select a bank based on availability in two areas?

Tags: banking, international, research

Suppose I will be frequently moving back and forth between Country A and Country B. I would prefer to work with a bank which has many offices and ATMs (so I can avoid the fee for using another bank's ATM) in either country, ideally in the cities I frequent (or better yet has branches in most cities so that I know I can reach them wherever I go in these countries).

For example, suppose I live in London, and frequently travel to France. I definitely want a bank with an Office in London, so I can do my banking business easily when at home. I also want the bank to have branches and ATMs in most cities of France, since I don't know whether I will be in Paris, or Marseilles, or somewhere else. (This example is trivial, since most banks do have extensive operations in France and UK, but this is not the case for all countries.)

So I would like to know the answer to at least one of the following:

1. How can I get two lists of banks most active in country A and country B respectively (activity being distribution/number of ATMs and offices)? If I had these separate rankings I could figure out which one is most active in both countries on my own.
2. How can I get a list of banks which both have an office in a specific City C of Country A, and offices or ATMs in many cities of Country B?

I am at a loss as to how I can efficiently research this information.

It would also be nice if I could have a way of filtering away banks such as HSBC, which have branches in many countries, but treat each branch separately so that if you have an account with, say, HSBC France, the HSBC offices in UK will not service you (and the only thing you get is basically free ATM usage).

Comment: You want one, and only one bank ? I don't. I want at least two.

Comment: HSBC, Standard Chartered, CitiBank, BNP Paribas, Barclays

Comment: There are also special multi-currency personal banking accounts specifically for this situation. Citi has one for instance: http://www.citibank.com/ipb-global/homepage/newsite/content/english/multicurrency.htm

Comment: Given that the UK and France use different currencies, are you sure you only want the one bank? You can often get much better deals for moving money between currencies+countries than a typical multi-currency account offers

Answer (score 1):

Asking a bank for which ATM/branch network it belongs to and where those networks are would be your best bet.

Comment: That's certainly what I just did for a trip over the puddle -- I checked with my credit union regarding which ATM networks would be available to me without fees, did a very quick search to confirm that those networks covered everywhere I was likely to go, decided not to worry about it, and this worked just fine for drawing cash in the local currency when I needed it. Exchange rate was pretty decent too.